# Cannot open file for writing error when I use the VS2017 to compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I compile my source code to run, sometimes it leads to question like that.  I don't know the reason of this problem, and I want to ask how I can solve this problem?

It is the first time I ask question there. It seems that I fail to upload the picture.

[image]

[I can't close the background process here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdyIF.png)

Comment: Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages, particularly [ask], before posting your next question here. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry. My English is pool. I will read them carefully later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left your program running when you tried to recompile it, so it couldn't replace the old program with the new one.

Comment: Thanks, but I am sure I have close the running program. I wonder if the background process can lead to this problem, but when I try to close the background process, it happen nothing when I clicked the "Terminate button".

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer, your program did not end successfully!